# Replacing full stop in url with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send some parameters in a url but the parameter `rvn` is throwing an error because it has a full stop in it (it's a price). How can I get around this? I don't want to strip out the full stop so need to replace it with something.

Here's my full url:

```
https://example.com/subscription.js?tid=GC-54541&subid=SUBS-9634-REO&rvn=6.6&cid=17268
```

Here's my code that's generating it:

```
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $callback = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/subscription.js?aid=c-a-totmsubs-uk', [
        'query' => [
                'tid' => $transaction_id,
                'subid' => $reference,
                'rvn' => $total_price,
                'cid' => $customer_id,
            ]
        ]);
        $status = $callback->getStatusCode();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$status');</script>";
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? How do you create this URL?

Comment: url-encode the parameters on url-assembly (full stop would be %2E)

Comment: and what's the error message?

Comment: on js file where you are retriving `rvn` you can use `parseFloat(yourvariable)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about replacing the fullstop in your get params with something else, you can use this function:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/subscription.js?tid=GC-54541&subid=SUBS-9634-REO&rvn=6.6&cid=17268';

function replaceFullstop($url, $with) {
    $url = explode('?', $url);

    $url1 = $url[0] . '?';
    $url2 = str_replace('.', $with, $url[1]);

    return $url1 . $url2;
}

echo replaceFullstop($url, '_');
```